# SQL - How to split values in field with commas in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, django

I have a field in a MySQL table with `'3,4,7,16'` in it.
These values are store in another table

```
id - value
1 - name1
2 - name2
...
16 - name16
```

I would like to get then in 4 rows

```
3
4
7
16
```

I have seen many answer but they need temporary table, function, loop or procedure.
I am using **Django ORM** and it is not possible to use procedure in Django query.
Can you help to solve this issue ?

Comment: Hi @Hermann retrieve few specific id as comma separated id.

Comment: Yes, do you want to share a link ?

Comment: You want a solution to get query results but you cannot use a query? How does that make sense?

Comment: Every ORM I've seen has a means of running a custom SQL query, because ORM's inevitably do not support every type of query. For example in Django ORM you can [use the raw() function to run a custom query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/).

Comment: Hi @Hermann please check the url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=636688d37ba6cbfd8c42d378f840dac9

Comment: Hi @Hermann if you want this result then I'll write this query as my answer.

Comment: '3,4,7,16' is a string field value. the problem is to convert this string value into rows.